# no option to have more app icons, but still causing warning

Tags: xcode

I am getting a warning when I build "A 76x76 app icon is required for iPad apps targeting..."

but under app icons I only see this. Why do I not see the ipad ones? How do I make them show up?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the iPad icons checkbox in the attributes inspector:

[image]